# Replicating Cargocollective jquery/lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, plugins

I have a site on cargocollective from a very long time ago.
http://cargocollective.com/ruimelo

And I'm in the process of building a new one not using Cargo, however I like the way Cargocollective displays work in this theme. Whereas each piece is shown with a small thumbnail, you click it and it stretches out displaying the full image and brief description.

I'm sure this has been done before but for the life of me I can't find it, or a similar jQuery plugin online, and I'm definitely not up to snuff when it comes to write JS myself.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would be very thankful!

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest you can get is using [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com) plugin.
See this little demo I created http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/838Bf/1/

So basicly what you need to do is just load project data via AJAX and put into corresponding container. Ther rest will be handled by plugin.

Usage of plugin is pretty simple like

```
$('ul').masonry({
    itemSelector: 'li',
    columnWidth: 100
});
```